# Ошибка setData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android-studio

Всем привет. У меня есть приложение для заметок. Я решил добавить в него отображение времени создания каждой заметки. Всё почти получилось, но в файле MainAdapter(адаптере для RecyclerView, отображающего список заметок) появилась ошибка, а именно в строке `holder.setData(mainArray.get(position).getTitle());` А ошибка следующая:'setData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'com.masterok.calendar.adapter.MainAdapter.MyViewHolder' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)' Из за чего эта ошибка возникла, и как её  устранить? Код привожу ниже:

MainAdapter.java:

```
package com.masterok.calendar.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.masterok.calendar.EditActivity;
import com.masterok.calendar.R;
import com.masterok.calendar.db.MyConstants;
import com.masterok.calendar.db.MyDbManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MainAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<ListItem> mainArray;

    public MainAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        mainArray = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_layout, parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, context, mainArray);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(mainArray.get(position).getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mainArray.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    private final TextView tvTitle;
    private final TextView tvTime;
    private final Context context;
    private final List<ListItem> mainArray;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, Context context, List<ListItem> mainArray) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            this.mainArray = mainArray;
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MyConstants.LIST_ITEM_INTENT, mainArray.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            i.putExtra(MyConstants.EDIT_STATE, false);
            context.startActivity(i);


        }


        public void setData(String title, String time) {
            tvTitle.setText(title);
            tvTime.setText(time);
        }
    }
    public void updateAdapter(List<ListItem> newList){
        mainArray.clear();
        mainArray.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void removeItem(int pos, MyDbManager dbManager){
        dbManager.delete(mainArray.get(pos).getId());
        mainArray.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, mainArray.size());
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);


    }

}
```

EditActivity.java(экран добавления/редактирования заметки):

```
package com.masterok.calendar;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.masterok.calendar.adapter.ListItem;
import com.masterok.calendar.db.AppExecutor;
import com.masterok.calendar.db.MyConstants;
import com.masterok.calendar.db.MyDbManager;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int PICK_IMAGE_CODE = 123;
    private ImageView imNewImage;
    private ConstraintLayout imageContainer;
    private ImageButton imEditImage, imDeleteImage;
    private FloatingActionButton fbAddImage;
    private EditText edTitle, edDesc;
    private MyDbManager myDbManager;
    private String tempUri = "empty";
    private boolean isEditState = true;
    private ListItem item;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
        init();
        getMyIntents();



    }

    private void init() {
        myDbManager = new MyDbManager(this);
        edTitle = findViewById(R.id.edTitle);
        imNewImage = findViewById(R.id.imNewImage);
        fbAddImage = findViewById(R.id.fbAddImage);
        imageContainer = findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);
        imEditImage = findViewById(R.id.imEditImage);
        imDeleteImage = findViewById(R.id.imDeleteImage);
        edDesc = findViewById(R.id.edDesc);
    }

    private void getMyIntents() {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i != null) {
            item = (ListItem) i.getSerializableExtra(MyConstants.LIST_ITEM_INTENT);
            isEditState = i.getBooleanExtra(MyConstants.EDIT_STATE, true);

            if (!isEditState) {
                edTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
                edDesc.setText(item.getDesc());
                if (!item.getUri().equals("empty")) {
                    tempUri = item.getUri();
                    imageContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imNewImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(item.getUri()));
                    imDeleteImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imEditImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

            }

        }

    }


    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CODE && data != null) {

            tempUri = data.getData().toString();
            imNewImage.setImageURI(data.getData());
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(data.getData(), Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


        }

    }


    public void onClickSave(View view) {

        final String title = edTitle.getText().toString();
        final String desc = edDesc.getText().toString();
        if (title.equals("") || desc.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.empty, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (isEditState) {
                myDbManager.openDb();
                AppExecutor.getInstance().getSubIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myDbManager.insertToDb(title, desc, tempUri, getCurrentTime());
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                myDbManager.openDb();
                myDbManager.updateItem(title, desc, tempUri, item.getId(), getCurrentTime());
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            myDbManager.closeDb();
            finish();

        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed () {
        super.onBackPressed();

        final String title = edTitle.getText().toString();
        final String desc = edDesc.getText().toString();
        if (title.equals("") || desc.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.empty, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (isEditState) {
                myDbManager.openDb();
                AppExecutor.getInstance().getSubIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myDbManager.insertToDb(title, desc, tempUri, getCurrentTime());
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                myDbManager.openDb();
                myDbManager.updateItem(title, desc, tempUri, item.getId(), getCurrentTime());
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            myDbManager.closeDb();
            finish();

        }
    }




    public void onClickDeleteImage(View view) {

        imNewImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_def);
        tempUri = "empty";
        imageContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fbAddImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onClickAddImage(View view) {
        imageContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    public void onClickChooseImage(View view) {
        Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        chooser.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(chooser, PICK_IMAGE_CODE);

    }
    private String getCurrentTime(){
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return formatter.format(date);



    }


}
```

Listitem.java:

```
package com.masterok.calendar.adapter;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ListItem implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private String uri = "empty";
    private String time = "";

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private int id = 0;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `setData` определён в классе `MyViewHolder` с **двумя** обязательными параметрами, и затем вызывается в `MainAdapter` только с одним:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(mainArray.get(position).getTitle());

}
```

Исправьте либо вызов метода (добавьте параметр), либо его определение(уберите лишний параметр); также можно добавить (overload) метод, принимающий только один параметр.